# Aggregation in Mongo through Python using Jupyter Notebook : Empty Result

Tags: python, mongodb, group-by, pymongo, aggregation

I have the following code in Jupyter notebook to do an aggregation in Mongo which I have my free tier connection in a cluster. It should be said, that this code was taken from the course: Introduction to MongoDB offered in the platform of Coursera, anyhow in case you ask where I was taking that from. As result is giving me '[]'.

In case you asked; yes I have tried to reach the tutors in charge of the course but they have stopped answering for a couple of years to all the students.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint
from IPython.display import clear_output


client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://IVAN:*****@vanillacluster.kzjwz.mongodb.net/MFLIX?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

pipeline = [{ '$group': { '_id': {"language": "$language"},  'count': {'$sum': 1} }}]
clear_output()
pprint.pprint(list(client.MFLIX.movies_initial.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

Comment: easy peasy. go back to your atlas cluster, look for the "network" list item, and edit the IP from the current value to `0.0.0.0/0`. see the magic. Added to this, I suspect you need to replace `MFLIX` by `admin`

Comment: Thanks Minsky for dedicating some time of yours to answer, however editing the IP to that value you are suggesting was already done and it still has the same result, []

Comment: can you confirm the `client` is nt empty?

Comment: Hi everyone, issue is solved, it was a matter of granting access to the user, thanks for the ideas!

Comment: how come ??????

Comment: I had to enable my user with admin settings within my free tier cluster.

Comment: good to know. you can remove the post.

Comment: Could you explain how you did it @IvanGG ?? I can't find how to fix it. Having the same [] problem.

Comment: William, it has been some time since I experienced this issue, but as I can remember it was a very simple obstacle to tackle, you only have to grant your profile as admin but it has to be through the Mongo CMD